# is this struts 1.x form bean in session scope or request scope?

Tags: forms, scope, struts-1, struts-config

I have been searching for a concrete answer for this, as much of google returns a lot of very old posts. Is this `greetingActionForm` in the request scope, or in the session scope? Is there any location besides the `action` and `form-bean` declaration to determine a form's scope?

```xml
<action-mappings>
    <action path="/hello/my/oldfriend"
            type="com.imFine.HowAreYouAction"
            name="greetingActionForm"
            validate="true"
            input="/the/front/door">
        <forward name="success" path="/go/get/drinks.do" />
    </action>
</action-mappings>
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="greetingActionForm" type="com.forms.GreetingActionForm"/>
</form-beans>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**If unspecified, by default an ActionForm will have scope `session`.**

The scope of an ActionForm is specified on the `<action>` configuration as attribute `scope`. You can find this in the Struts [DTD](http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd):

```
The "action" element describes an ActionMapping object that is to be used
     to process a request for a specific module-relative URI. The following
     attributes are defined:
     .....
     .....
     scope           The context ("request" or "session") that is used to
                     access our ActionForm bean, if any.  Optional if "name" is
                     specified, else not valid. [session]
     .....
     .....
```

This value is initialized in the [org.apache.struts.config.ActionConfig](http://struts.apache.org/1.1/api/org/apache/struts/config/ActionConfig.html) class which represents the configuration information of an  element from a Struts module configuration file:

```
/**
 * <p> Identifier of the scope ("request" or "session") within which our
 * form bean is accessed, if any. </p>
 */
protected String scope = "session";
```